# How disable actor restore?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am writing test to persistent actor. So the problem is that during test Actor fail and then restarted automatically, get fail again and again restarts again and again... This loop leads to slow build process and enormous log file (about ~50 Mb, when normal size less that 1Mb).

So how I can disable auto restart actor when it fail(just for test and debugging processes)? What setting parameters are resposible for that?

Answer (score 4):

The policy for dealing a failed actors is dictated by the [supervisor strategy](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fault-tolerance.html) of the actor's supervisor.

The supervisor is the actor that started the actor. Override `supervisorStrategy` in the supervisor:

```
override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() { case _ => Stop }
```

Or if it's a top-level actor, the supervisor is the [user guardian](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html#user-guardian). You can configure the user guardian's strategy with the `akka.actor.guardian-supervisor-strategy` config option (specify the class name of a `SupervisorStrategyConfigurator`).

Comment: I uses Spring wit akka. I have added `actor {guardian-supervisor-strategy="akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy"}` to my cofiguration and get error - `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public akka.actor.ActorSystem com.my.service.SpringActorSystem.actorSystem()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: interface akka.actor.SupervisorStrategyConfigurator is not assignable from class akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy`.

Comment: @Cherry You should probably read what a SupervisorStrategyConfigurator is. http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.1/index.html#akka.actor.SupervisorStrategyConfigurator

Comment: I have read and do not understand how disable actor restarting just from configuration. Not to ovverride `supervisorStrategy` in every supervisor.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to change the default supervisor strategy for every actor.